# Avoiding rounding errors in diffusion simulation

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose the diffusion has initial condition $\mathbb{1}_{\{|x|\le1\}}$ on the real line and start spreading out at time $t=0$. To solve matrix equation iteratively, every time the solution to the next period is popped with small rounding error where they're supposed to be zero. Since I'm interested in the extinction time of the population equation, these rounding error makes the population harder to die out. How to avoid this to happen?

Comment: I corrected a few typographical errors. We need more information to help. Specifically, we need the exact partial differential equation that you are solving. I suspect that the exact solution will decay as $t$ increases, but that it will always be strictly positive. What you need is (probably) the ability to determine when rounding errors dominate the calculation. For this we also need to know *how* you are solving your equations. Avoiding rounding errors completely is typically not feasible.

Comment: Its actually a spde being strictly positive and may or may not decaying. And I want to estimate the extinction probability. You interpretation is correct. The way I solve it is using Crank-Nicolson and solve matrix equation. And as you may have known, matrix equation suffer from rounding error especially when this is obvious starting from a concentrated initial condition, these error spread out very fast.

Comment: Normally, Crank-Nicolson's method requires the solution of a standard linear system $Ax=b$ in order to advance from one time to the next. This  is not a matrix equation, such as, say, the continuous time Lyapunov matrix equation. $AX+XA^T=BB^T$. Moreover, unless you have boundary conditions, I don't see how you can have a finite dimensional problem. Either you provide the information I suggested, i.e. the exact problem and the numerical method used or your chances of getting a useful reply will remain *very* low.

Comment: I have updated the post with my code and problem statement

Comment: Your matrix as implemented is strictly diagonally dominant by rows with a dominance factor which is $\epsilon = 10^4/(10^4+600) < 0.95$. It is well conditioned with an infinity norm condition number less than $(1+\epsilon)/(1-\epsilon) < 2/0.05 =40$. This is about as good as it gets. I am hard pressed to believe that this is the source of your problem. Can you include an minimal working example which highlights your problem? Be sure to include the seed fed to random generator so that your numbers can be reproduced.